# How to use a color instead of drawable for toggle button selector

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, selector, togglebutton

```
<ToggleButton 
        android:id="@+id/toggle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/check"   
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected, use grey -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected_image"
          android:state_checked="true" />
    <!-- When not selected, use white-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/unselected_image"
        android:state_checked="false"/>

 </selector>
```

How can use a **color** instead of a **drawable**?

I tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/bg_blue"/>
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="@color/bg_light_grey"/>

</selector>
```

defined the above selector in color folder with name **bg_toggle.xml**

and

```
android:background="@color/bg_toggle"
```

which gives an Exception:

**android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #50: Error inflating class android.widget.ToggleButton**

**org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4:  tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable**

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/bg_blue"/>
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@color/bg_light_grey"/>

 </selector>
```

**EDIT**

From android [Doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

> Note: A color resource can also be used as a drawable in XML. For example, when creating a state list drawable, you can reference a color resource for the android:drawable attribute (android:drawable="@color/green").

Comment: Can i use a **color** in **drawable attribute**? like **android:drawable="@color/bg_blue"**

Answer (score -2):

Instead of that try like this:

```
  ToggleButton btnToggle=(ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.<Your ToggleButtonId>);
    btnToggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked)
                buttonView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            else buttonView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
    });
```

Comment: It is generally considered better practice to handle ui states with xml selectors.